# CSS round cone shape in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, css-shapes

I'm working in a App project using the Ionic framework. I am trying to make a navigation button for TV remote control. My objective is to make the buttons like the image in the link below (from kodi ios remote App) using CSS.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/ademilter/pen/Dwelk) - NOT MINE but related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

define your wrapper and rotate it at 45deg

[image]

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
:root{
    background: skyblue;
    height: 100vh
}
figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg)
}
.btn {
    width: 123px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #000;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transition: background .3s ease;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 0px rgb(187, 187, 187);
}

.btn:hover{cursor: pointer; background: #4864e3;}

.btn:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 0;
}

.btn:nth-of-type(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.btn:last-of-type {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

figure figcaption{
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 10px #000,
                inset 0 0 3px 2px #000,
                0 0 0px 32px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background:-webkit-gradient(radial, 29 0, 0, 220 -257, 455, from(#4864e3), to(#000E1A));
}
.btn:before{
    content:'';
    opacity: .6;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 32px solid transparent;
    border-right: 32px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 32px solid rgb(187, 187, 187)
}
.btn:first-of-type:before {
    top: 44px;
    left: 24px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.btn:nth-of-type(2):before {
    top: 40px;
    left: 32px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn:nth-of-type(3):before {
    top: 48px;
    left: 26px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.btn:last-of-type:before {
    top: 48px;
    left: 32px;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <div class=btn></div>
    <div class=btn></div>
    <div class=btn></div>
    <div class=btn></div>
    <figcaption>NAV</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: awesome! :) Great demo :)

Comment: @Tambo. Great. Fantastic. This is exacly what i was looking for. However i didnt understand the code. Could you please point me some CSS corse for this kind of stuff. The other thing is that is too big for an iphone screen. could you tell me how to make it smaller.

Comment: @PatricioCordeiro You are welcome. to make it smaller or bigger  in `figure` replace `transform: rotate(45deg)` with `transform: rotate(45deg) scale(.5,.5)` where `(.5,.5)` is the `value` you are looking for.

Comment: @Tambo. Thank you very much. One question: How do i make the NAV to be a button?. Im really like to learn how to do this kind of stuff in css. Could you point me to a start point. Thank you.

Comment: @PatricioCordeiro  my favorite ( Dan Cederholm, Ethan Marcotte-Handcrafted CSS ) you can have a look at 1-Alexis Goldstein-Learning CSS3 Animations and Transitions  2-Css3 for web designers 3-Pro HTML5 and CSS3 Design Patterns 4-Dudley Storey-Pro CSS3 Animation-Apress 5-CSS3- The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition  . concerning the NAV buttons you can use javascript EventTarget.addEventListener()  click.

Comment: @Tambo Thank you. About the NAV: The midle button with text NAV  is not a button. How could i make it a button like the others four.

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible to do using css and maybe fontawesome (though it would not turn out nearly as nice as the image you provided)... it would be far easier and more practical to use an image for this.  This is one of those cases of, it can be done but is it worth the effort?

Perhaps these tutorials would get you started on the right foot:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-on-off-button/

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-button-tutorials/